# problems with mixrgb for background

Tags: node-editor

I made a sky and would like to mix some stars into it, using a voronoi texture. Unfortunately when i mix the color of the background together with the voronoi texture, the color disappears.

This is the background on which i would like to have some stars:

[image]

And this happens when i mix them together:

[image]

My .blend file

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest possible solution for your question is to add 2 nodes Invert and Math

Or invert colorRamp itself

Basically, you only need to invert, but the math node will give you the option to make stars more white:

[image]

The reason why it didn't work for you was that you needed to invert white and black values.... black values get your blue color and white don't, by inverting it you get what you need.

2nd option that is quicker is to simply swap black and white on your colorRamp:
[image]

Edit: And I forgot, ColorRamp that goes from voronoi, change the first color back to black, don't make it light blue

Comment: perfect, thanks a lot